# Roles in Features: Are they always imported in alphabetical order?

Tags: users, features

This is a request for more information outside of what was given here: [User roles and keeping their IDs when using features](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20294/user-roles-and-keeping-their-ids-when-using-features)

Basically, it's the age-old problem of storing Roles in Features, and then migrating or importing them into a new site.

Based on some observations of mine when putting roles into a feature failed, it seems like Drupal takes the Role Feature and imports the stored roles in alphabetical order.

For example, I have some roles on my site that I stored into a feature. They had been originally created and added to my development site in this order:

- administrator
- moderator
- subscriber
- training
- announcer
- blogger
- manager

However, when I migrated the Features code to a new version of the site on a fresh database install, Drupal took the roles Feature I created, and imported the roles it contained in the following order:

- administrator RID -> 3
- announcer RID -> 4
- blogger RID -> 5
- manager RID -> 6
- moderator RID -> 7
- subscriber RID -> 8
- training RID -> 9

Is this normal behavior? And, if I just organize my roles into Features in alphabetical order, can I expect them to always be reimported in the same proper RID heirarchy?

Answer (score 1):

Roles being imported in alphabetical order has been my experience, too.

**But counting on autoincrement IDs to be consistent between multiple sites is never a good idea.**

I recommend, instead of relying on the autoincrement IDs to be generated in a particular order, to avoid using autoincrement IDs.

- For Drupal 6 and Drupal 7, the [Role Export](http://drupal.org/project/role_export) module turns Role IDs into hashes of machine names, so they're consistent from site to site, regardless of import order.
- For Drupal 8, [work is in progress](http://drupal.org/node/935062) to eliminate autoincrement Role IDs altogether.

Comment: Yeah, I feel like your warning is a good one. I was just hoping to not have to use yet another module to deal with site migration.